# How to model an end date which might not end in the near future

Tags: mysql, user-interface

How to model an end date which might not end in the near future. I have a start (mandatory) & end date and end date can be  by the user or marked as doesn't have an end date.

1. How do you model this, so that I can handle queries effectively. Should I leave the end date as null and introspect accordingly.
2. How do I render such a selection for end date in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

1. Model the missing end-date as null
2. Define a MAX_DATE (say 12/31/2999) that is so far in the future that it will never be reached.

The first option "feels" more correct but makes range checking more complex. The second option makes range checking easier, but requires special handling in the UI to display it as "no end date".

Take your pick.